# Migrating data from Identity Server 3

Tags: identityserver3, data-migration

So IdentityServer3 stores grant data in tokens table. What I am trying to figure out is how does it create a key corresponding to access token or refresh token?

If I check the code for IdentityServer3, it shows like below:

```
            Token accessToken = await _tokenService.CreateAccessTokenAsync(tokenRequest);
            string refreshToken = "";
            if (createRefreshToken)
            {
                refreshToken = await _refreshTokenService.CreateRefreshTokenAsync(tokenRequest.Subject, accessToken, request.Client);
            }

            var securityToken = await _tokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(accessToken);
```

When I use the access token received, for validation, how does it figure out corresponding security token based on that access token?

I am trying to decode the data stored in database for IdentityServer3 to migrate to a new authorization server we have built. Is this possible even?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

What identity server 3 does (for a key it stores in database):

```
1. It generates an access token and refresh token.
2. For these generated tokens, it creates UTF-8 encoded bytes
3. It hashes the byte data with SHA-256 algorithm
4. And it Base64 encode hashed data from step 3.
```